# Twitter gadget does not load when going to sub page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I am using the twitter gadget for my website: https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/

I created a gadget that loads on each page. On the home page it works fine, but when I am going to a sub page it only shows the alternative text. What am I doing wrong?

The weird thing is when I reload the sub page with the F5 key, the twitter gadgets works fine.

I am using HTML5, CSS, JQuery and Javascript for my website.

Comment: please post the code you are using.

Comment: How are you loading in the sub page?